# Reverse Index Swipe on card_swiper

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using [card_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/card_swiper), and I can't find the way to invert horizontally index swipe.

I'm getting index 0,1,2,3... when moving to right, and lasts index when moving to left.

I need this inverted, get 4,3,2,1,0 starting at 0, when moving to left.

I know there should be a simple solution to this, even built into the package, but I can't find it.

I tried changing  `axisDirection: AxisDirection.left,` from the name seemed to do this, but it doesn't.

```
Swiper(
      axisDirection: AxisDirection.right,
      autoplay: false,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(child: Container(height: 200, width: 200, child: Center(child: Text('$index'))));
      },
    ),
```

Comment: how about itemCount.length - index

Comment: @DungNgo, sorry I don't understand, the possible solution you gave me

Comment: I think the simple solution to your problem is to use your itemCount (in your case: 5) and minus the index you get from swiping to the right (0, 1, 2, ... ) to get the inverted index (4, 3, 2, 1, 0)